# how to parsing array to MYSQL IN()?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm have a problem when I want to query to the database , in this case I want to using IN() mysql function for searching data by value field on array.

example I have array from php

```
$data = array(1,2,3,4);
```

and this is my query code to selection data on table Employee

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM employee_tbl 
    -> WHERE daily_typing_pages IN ' .$data.;
```

when I'm execute that code I have error like this

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Array 
SELECT * FROM employee_tbl 
        -> WHERE daily_typing_pages IN Array;
```

I think that error is come because Array read as string,and don't parse to this format `(1,2,3,4)`

how i can convert to that format ? 
any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`implode()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to create an actual comma-separated list of items as a string.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM employee_tbl 
    -> WHERE daily_typing_pages IN (' . implode(",", $data) . ")";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
$data = array(1,2,3,4);
$ids = join(',',$data);  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee_tbl WHERE daily_typing_pages IN ($ids)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, use [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to converts array into string

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM employee_tbl 
        -> WHERE daily_typing_pages IN  ( ".implode(',',$data)." ) ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$x = array(1,2,3,4);
$y = implode(',',$x);
```